# QT QML error : can't apply a state change as part of a state definition

Tags: qt, qml, state

I'am struggling with the issue indicated in the title.
When trying to switch state after a custom signal made from C++ was triggered, i have this error coming from my QML script : can't apply a state change as part of a state definition.

I have barely found information about that same error on internet and i have struggling for days trying to fix this without success. Regarding the error, it's assumed that i'm trying to change state in a state definition but it's definitely not the case.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
Connections {
    target: timer
    function onTriggered() {rectangle.state = "welcomeState"}
}

Connections {
    target: testBack
    function onPrintDataReady() {rectangle.state = "printState"}
}

Connections {
    target: boutonOui
    function onPressed() {rectangle.state = "endState";testBack.printFile() }
}

Connections {
    target: boutonNon
    function onPressed() {rectangle.state = "endState"}
}
```

And the states are defined here:

```
states: [

    State {
        name: "welcomeState"
        
        PropertyChanges {
            target: logo_2
            visible: false
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: messageFin
            visible: false
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: boutonOui
            visible: false
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: boutonNon
            visible: false
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: impressionTicket
            visible: false
        }
    },

    State {
        name: "printState"

        PropertyChanges {
            target: boutonOui
            visible: true
            text: qsTr("OUI")
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: boutonNon
            visible: true
            text: "NON"
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: logo_1
            visible: false
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: impressionTicket
            visible: true
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: logo_2
            visible: true
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: messageFin
            visible: false
            text: qsTr("Merci de votre visite. A bientôt.")
        }
    },

    State {
        name: "endState"
        
        PropertyChanges {
            target: logo_1
            visible: false
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: logo_2
            visible: true
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: messageFin
            visible: true
            text: qsTr("Merci de votre visite. A bientôt.")
            anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 1
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 1
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: boutonNon
            visible: false
            text: qsTr("NON")
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: impressionTicket
            visible: false
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: boutonOui
            visible: false
        }

        PropertyChanges {
            target: timer
            running: true
            triggeredOnStart: false
            interval: 6000
        }
    }
]
```

I can't switch to the state "printState" for the target "testBack". "testBack" is a C++ object made accessible in QML imported from C++ and so, `onPrintDataReady()` is a custom signal.

And the first state is "welcomeState":

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    width: 800
    height: Constants.height
    color: "#eb5a2d"
    state: "welcomeState"
    property alias messageFin: messageFin
    property alias logo_1: logo_1
    property bool property0: true
```

That transition is the only one that is not working among the 4 transition that are indicated.
Any help would be appreciated.

I made sure that the `onPrintDataReady()` was fired by changing the color of the rectangle instead of the state and it worked.
I tried to made the connection directly in the item "testBack" but the issue was still here.
I set the variable STATECHANGE_DEBUG to 1 but didn't give me any interesting information for my problem.
Tried the other transitions and it's all working except the one that is in `testBack`
And now i'm running out of idea.

Comment: Unsure if the code above is sufficient for understanding. Where is that `states` defined? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#state-prop besides `state`.

Comment: @AlexanderV just edited my initial post with the states definition

Comment: It seems to me that the `state` transition started in `function onPressed() {rectangle.state = "endState";testBack.printFile() }` causes `function onPrintDataReady() {rectangle.state = "printState"}` with another state transition immediately. This can be overcome with detaching `testBack.printFile()` call as part of another timer with 0 delay trigger event. All I can say as still not all clear. So you should trigger the timer to cause another nested state transition instead. `testPrintTimer.start()` or so for non-repeating idle timer.

Comment: @AlexanderV the first state is "welcomeState" (just edited the initial post" so the first transition start from "welcomeState" to "printState".
Trying to give as many info as possible but posting the whole QML script might make everything not understandable and the post too long.

Comment: The root of the problem shows in "can't apply a state change as part of a state definition". You need to figure out why after initial `state = "SomeState1"` there is immediately another `state = "SomeState2"` before the transition finished.

Comment: @AlexanderV Not sure to understand what you mean. At start up, i set the rectangle item state to  `state: "welcomeState" `, so i go imediatly from the default state to the `welcomeState` . This behavior is normal at this step. 
My issue is that i can't go from "welcomeState" to "printState" for some reason. But i can go from "printState" to "endState" and frome "endState" to "welcomeState" without any issues.

Comment: While switching to new state you have that `state` variable assigned again somehow. This is how I read the error message: " can't apply a state change as part of a state definition."

Comment: Personally, i understand something elses. I understand that a state should not be assigned in the state definition (so the "state" item). But here, it's not the case at all.

Comment: I suspect this `Connections {
    target: timer
    function onTriggered() {rectangle.state = "welcomeState"}
}` being triggered from "endState" state definition. Whether or not this interpreted per definition or a run-time is hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a turnaroud.
Instead of going from`welcomeState` to `printState` through the `onPrintDataReady` signal, i activated a timer when `printerDataReady` was triggered and when receiving the trigger signal from this timer, i did the transition from `welcomeState` to `printState` so this is what i have now :

```
    Connections {
    target: timer3
    function onTriggered() {testBack.waitForPrint()}
    }

    Connections {
    target: timer2
    function onTriggered() {rectangle.state = "welcomeState"}
    } 

    Connections {
    target: testBack
    function onPrintDataReadyChanged() {timer.start()}    
    }

    Connections {
    target: timer
    function onTriggered() {rectangle.state = "printState"}
    } 

    Connections {
    target: boutonOui
    function onPressed() {rectangle.state = "endState";testBack.printFile()}
    }

    Connections {
    target: boutonNon
    function onPressed() {rectangle.state = "endState"}
    }
```